# Maxlength in lat and long google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, maxlength

I'm trying to use the maxlength in input button to show the latitude and longitude of the google maps, but maxlenght doesn't work... What am I doing wrong?

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   draggable: true,
   position: {lat: -47.00, lng: 18.00},
   map: map,
   });
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
   document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
   document.getElementById("long").value = event.latLng.lng();
});
```

HTML:

```
Latitu: <input id="lat" name="lat" maxlength="6" value=""> <br />
Longi:  <input id="long" name="long" maxlength="6" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fe-maxlength):

> declares a limit on the number of characters a user can input

When you set the value via JS it's not a input by the user.

You'll need to limit the number of characters via JS:

```
document.getElementById("lat").value = String(event.latLng.lat()).substr(0,6);
```